# How to show that the solution of a delayed differential equation is unique? Can you use Picard Lindelof theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

So I know that you can use Picard Lindelof to show uniqueness of a solution to an ODE, but if given an ordinary *delayed* differential equation, could you still use it? How would that establish uniqueness for all values of, say, t, if I were trying to show uniqueness for something like
$$y'(t) = ay(t-1)$$ with $y(t) = y_0$ on $[-1,0]$?

I'm reading "An Introduction to Delay Differential Equations with Sciences Applications to the Life Sciences," and the existence and uniqueness part,,, doesn't quite make much sense to me, even though I understand what the method of steps itself is, so... :/

Also, side question. Is it sufficient to show that $y'(t)$ and its derivative are continuous to show existence/uniqueness?

(I'm trying to show uniqueness for the solution of a different DDE, but I want to try to understand it first, which is why I added a much simpler problem instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, you do not need much. You can apply what is called forward propagation (or the method of steps).

First consider $t\in[0,1]$. In that case, we have that

$$y'(t)=\alpha y_0(t-1),$$

and this has the simple unique solution $$y(t)=y_0(0)+\alpha\int_0^ty_0(s-1)ds.$$ Let us call it $y_1(t)$.

Now, consider $t\in[1,2]$. In that case, we have that

$$y'(t)=\alpha y_1(t-1),$$

and we have that the unique solution on $[1,2]$ is given by

$$y(t)=y_1(1)+\alpha\int_1^ty_1(s-1)ds,$$

and so on.

All linear systems with delays can be shown to have a unique solution using this approach. In the general single-delay case we have that

$$\dot{x}(t)=A_0x(t)+A_1x(t-h),\ x(s)=\varphi(s),\ s\in[-h,0].$$

Then, we have that

$$x(t)=\exp(A_0t)\varphi(0)+\int_0^t\exp(A(t-s))A_1\varphi(s-h)ds,\ t\in[0,h],$$

which is the unique solution. Propagating further we have that

$$x(t)=\exp(A_0(t-h))x(h)+\int_h^t\exp(A(t-s))A_1x(s-h)ds,\ t\in[h,2h],$$

etc.

Comment: Ahh alright, thank you!. So this is basically just using the method of steps, right? Also, in your second last line, just to clarify, the $A$ is supposed to be $A_0$, right? Also (last question), where can I read about this, if I need to give a reference?

Comment: Wait, sorry, actual last question. Why does this imply a unique solution? Is it because the integral has only one specific solution?

Comment: The uniqueness comes from the uniqueness of the solution of the resulting differential equations (no delay). You can check any book on delay systems such as Diekmann et al., "Delay Equations".

Comment: Sorry I'm back, one more question. What if I used this theorem: Let $f(t, x,y)$ and $f_x(t, x,y)$ be continuous on $R^3$, $s ∈ R$, and let $φ :[s − r,s] → R$ be continuous. Then there exists σ > s and a unique solution of the initial-value problem  on [s−r,σ] for $y0
(t) = f(t,y(t), x(t −r))$? How would one get $f_x$ to be continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by "How would one get $f_x$ to be continuous?". Also, when mentioning a theorem, please always mention a source. Also, it seems that your comment has some typos which make it difficult to understand.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant how would one know that $f_x$ is continuous when given $y'(t) = f(t, y(t), x(t-r))$? (Yes, sorry there were some typos, but I think the rest is correct.) This is Theorem 3.1 in the book "An Introduction to Delay Differential Equations with Sciences Applications to the Life Sciences."

Comment: You need to compute $f_x$ and check if it is continuous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136445/discussion-between-applesauce44-and-kbs).